# There should be an option while asking a question on difficulty level of question from the questioner's point of view

Tags: feature-request

So I'm new to StackOverflow, and I consider myself a medium difficulty problem solver programmer/developer, but what I think is, there should be an option while asking a question, where the questioner would select the difficulty level of question, and then people who want to answer some questions, they can search their "level" of questions. Just a suggestion/feature request, because I find myself searching a lot of questions for answering a single question.

Comment: Isn't difficulty subjective?

Comment: dont think askers can guage _difficulty level_ based on their issue.Subjective based on users as well as on specific area/language/technology etc...

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to spend my time searching for questions among haystack of questions whenever I am really into mood of solving someone's simple problem.

Comment: To illustrate perceived difficulty, let me give you a (In my view) simple question: Turn this input string: `"foo bar baz"` into an array: `["foo", " ", "bar", " ", "baz"]`. You can't use loops.

Comment: Yeah, but if you get a little better at that stuff and when you add a question, you atleast know that question comes under the category which beginners can solve or it can be solved by people with high experience

Comment: It's not a matter of __how much__ experience experience some has as one of __what__ experience one has.

Comment: And also I wrote that question to get little more privileges on StackOverflow, because I cannot comment on any question right now.

Comment: You can't earn Stack Overflow privileges from activity here on Meta

Comment: I can earn 5 some points if I ask questions on meta, it's written there.

Comment: Written where..?

Comment: @WedprakashWagh it _is the other way round_.. If you have 5 rep in SO you get to participate in meta. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta

Comment: It was somewhere, i can't find it now, I'll add a comment whenever I find it, it was something about adding a question on meta.

Comment: Alright, @SurajRao thanks for clearing it up!  I got confused over there! You're right, that was it, I mistook it to asking a question on meta and then getting those 5 points

Comment: To a questioner here, any question asked is difficult by definition, otherwise they wouldn't even ask.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out, so it must be impossible right?

Comment: That question was just something I made up to get what I thought would increase my privileges, I already know whatever I need to know, It was just something made up. Thank you for all your kind answers and downvotes, really appreciate you giving up your time to explain something made up.

Comment: @WedprakashWagh asking questions/posting answers strictly to gain reputation rarely work out. If you are looking for starting on SO using search is generally good idea - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+new+user+starts

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A concept that's *simple* to one person might be *incomprehensible* to another.

Perceived difficulty is extremely subjective, and as such, not very useful to SO.

Comment: Especially if the questioner is unsure what the actual issue is and as a result that would make ranking the difficulty of the question difficult in itself. Could be a simple typo or could be something much more complex, how would they know?